# conda minimum dependencies for jupyterlab with ipywidgets

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, ipywidgets

Trying to keep my Jupyter Lab projects sanitized and to avoid **base** environment non-used dependencies dead weight.

Ipywidgets works nicely with latest Anaconda (base) environment.

However I cannot get `ipywidgets` working on limited environment.yml, such as:

**environment.yml**

```
name: project_name
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ipywidgets
  - nodejs
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - bokeh
```

Alternatively, creating an environment with the following, and launching Jupyter Lab

```
conda create -n foo python=3.7.7 ipywidgets jupyterlab pandas numpy bokeh
conda activate foo
jupyter lab &
```

running a simple script, such as

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual 
import ipywidgets as widgets 

def f(x): 
  return x 

interact(f, x=10);
```

does not work.

However, the same script works in the Anaconda **base** env. Anyone have an idea about the minimum Conda env dependencies for `ipywidgets`?

Comment: `I cannot get ipywidgets working on limited environment.yml ` - I think you need to give more details about the problem, otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Comment: thanks for your reply, some more info
- running fedora 32
- Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12 (standard installation)
- I create conda environments from terminal
  for example: `conda create -n <env_name> python=3.7.7 ipywidgets jupyterlab pandas numpy bokeh
    conda activate <env_name>`
- start `jupyter lab &` 
- test simple ipywidgets script, for example 
  `from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
def f(x):
    return x
interact(f, x=10);`
works in (base) env but not in above limited env

Comment: I recall that I needed to install the ipywidgets lab extensions manually some time ago to make it work: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension